# Node server with reactJS meta tags

Tags: reactjs, tags

I'm trying to setup a new server with my blog (based on react).
Whenever the user is at url.com/blog/post/:id , it should get the ID of the post, fetch the post data and replace the META TAGS.
I was following this tutorial: https://blog.logrocket.com/adding-dynamic-meta-tags-react-app-without-ssr/.

Whenever the user is going to any other location , it should not do anything.
Here is my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const { getPostById } = require("./stub/posts");
const { default: next } = require("next");
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4200;
const indexPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "build", "index.html");
// here we serve the index.html page


app.get("/blog/post/:id", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("work");
    fs.readFile(indexPath, "utf8", (err, htmlData) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error("Error during file reading", err);
        return res.status(404).end();
      }
      // get post info
      const postId = req.query.id;
      const post = getPostById(postId);
      if (!post) return res.status(404).send("Post not found");
  
      // inject meta tags
      htmlData = htmlData
        .replace(
          "<title>Ofir The Freelancer</title>",
          `<title>${post.title}</title>`
        )
        .replace("__META_OG_TITLE__", post.title)
        .replace("__META_OG_DESCRIPTION__", post.description)
        .replace("__META_DESCRIPTION__", post.description);
      return res.send(htmlData);
    });
  });


app.get("/*", (req, res, next) => {
  fs.readFile(indexPath, "utf8", (err, htmlData) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Error during file reading", err);
      return res.status(404).end();
    }
    return res.send(htmlData);
  });
});

// static resources should just be served as they are
app.use(
  express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "build"), { maxAge: "30d" })
);

// listening...
app.listen(PORT, (error) => {
  if (error) {
    return console.log("Error during app startup", error);
  }
  console.log("listening on " + PORT + "...");
});
```

My approach was to return the index.html normally , unless the URL contains /blog/post/ , then we change the OG tags but unfortunately it doesn't work.
whenever I navigate with the  of the react router to the /blog/post/id page , it doesnt work.. but If I enter the /blog/post/id page directly from url, it does work. –

Comment: Does the `work` even print?

Comment: Its interesting, whenever I navigate with the <navHashLink> of the react router to the /blog/post/id page , it doesnt work.. but If I enter the /blog/post/id page directly from url, it does work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `navHashLink` changes url to `localhost:3000/#/blog/post/id` and not `localhost:3000/blog/post/id`

Comment: Just checked - I use the useNavigate history function to navigate to the /blog/post